# Как оформляют сноски в сносках

Tags: оформление-текста

Здравствуйте. Как оформляются сноски в сносках? Есть ли ссылки на примеры?

Хочу отдельно подчеркнуть, что я не ищу способа обойти эту сложную ситуацию, а задаю конкретный вопрос о том, как в книгах выглядит именно такая ситуация: есть примечание, а внутри примечание к примечанию, допустим, оба объёмные. О примерах приходилось слышать. Встречать — нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы найти пример, пришлось "стоптаться" в библиотеку.

[**Л. Купер. Физика для всех. Том 2. Современная физика (гл. 33, стр. 83)**](https://books.google.ee/books?id=RkP_AgAAQBAJ&pg=PA83&lpg=PA83&dq=%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%9C%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%20%D0%B8%20%D0%A3%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%8E&source=bl&ots=ZRdCkQoqY6&sig=To6CKlexUs9Z01p7oTR36tARn10&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjLutSkk_HYAhUSa1AKHWGUCNMQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%9C%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%20%D0%B8%20%D0%A3%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%8E&f=false) :

(...) Если при этом считать, что трение о воздух мешает такому естественному движению, то под подобным определением мог бы без сомнения подписаться сам Il maestro di color che sanno*.
Текст.
Фиг. 56.
Текст.
(...) теорию Максвелла с общей теорией относительности (т. е. создать так называемую единую теорию поля**).
Текст.
__
* Аристотель среди своих дохристианских друзей. Строчка из Песни IV "Божественной комедии" Данте. [В переводе М. Лозинского она звучит, как "Учитель тех, кто знает, семьей мудролюбивой окружен" (см., например, [ 1]).— *Прим. перев.*]
** Недавно Мизнер и Уилер [ 2] создали чисто геометрическую теорию классической электродинамики и гравитации(...).

В оригинале вместо звездочек стоят цифирки *1)* и *2)* — я не знаю, **как** их напечатать в ответе. Это постраничные (или подстрочные) сноски, внутри которых находятся концевые (или затекстовые) 1 и 2, оформленные в квадратных скобках.

Их расшифровка приводится в самом конце книги на стр. 379, в разделе ЛИТЕРАТУРА:

К главе 33

1. *Данте*, Божественная комедия, изд-во "Художественная литература", М., 1967, стр. 94.
2. *Misner C. W., Wheeler J. A.*, Ann. Phys., **2**, 529 (1957).

Пояснение
Даю так подробно, потому что ссылка может не "сработать". Похожий пример есть ещё в главе 41, стр. 176.

**Дополнение**

Нашелся ещё пример у А. Мильчина в "Справочнике издателя и автора" (даю две ссылки, вдруг какая-то не читается: [**1 [32.4.8]**](https://studfiles.net/preview/3577164/page:27/) и [**2**](https://books.google.ee/books?id=dv-mC8T4fasC&pg=PT1135&lpg=PT1135&dq=%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%20%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%20%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D0%B8%20%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%20%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%B2%20%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B5&source=bl&ots=X1YHwjWTAV&sig=woBPXznWdM1T9kWK4e-dl7IZd3E&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj4_ZXI3JHZAhWMblAKHYo-D0MQ6AEIMDAB#v=onepage&q=%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%20%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%20%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D0%B8%20%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%20%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%B2%20%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B5&f=false)).

**В основном тексте издания** (с. 196):
В июне 1974 г. принят Закон о народном образовании [220 107]*...

**В перечне затекстовых ссылок**:
220. Ведомости Верховного Совета Украинской ССР. Киев. 1941—1978.
1. 1941. №2. С.13 (222).
. . . . . . . .
107. 1974. №28. Ст.233 (196).
108. 1975. №37. Ст.419 (245).
. . . . . . . .
__
 * [220 107] — маленькое число 107 находится наверху справа от числа 220.

Answer (score 1):

Ну, тут стоит повыкручиваться, исходя из соображений эстетических: как ЭТО будет смотреться.

А догуглилась я до следующего (имхо, разумненького):

> **27.2.12. Ясность для читателя авторской принадлежности примечаний**
>
> У читателя не должно вызывать сомнения, кому принадлежат примечания,
>   особенно подстрочные. Достигается это самыми разными путями; ссылкой
>   об авт. принадлежности после текста примечания
>
> ---
>
> {Примеч. ред.; Примеч. авт. и т.п.); употреблением знаков сноски
>   разного вида для примечаний разной авт. принадлежности (с
>   соответствующей оговоркой в предисловии или в первом же примечании);
>   размещением примечаний разной авт. принадлежности в разных местах
>   издания (например, авторские и с переводом иноязычных текстов — под
>   строкой, а остальные издательские — за текстом, оговорив это в
>   предисловии или в первом примечании любого вида); указанием на то, что
>   все не содержащие ссылок на авт. принадлежность примечания написаны
>   таким-то лицом (обычно в качестве бессылочных примечаний выбирают те,
>   которых больше, т. к. это позволяет уменьшить объем).
>
> ---
>
> **27.2.13. Пояснение системы примечаний**
>
> При сложной системе примечаний полезно в изд. предисловии пояснить
>   принципы расположения примечаний и другие особенности принятой системы
>   их оформления. Это избавит читателя от необходимости самому
>   разбираться в особенностях системы примечаний в данном издании.
>
> ---
>
> **27.2.14. Исключение перекрестных ссылок к примечаниям, которые отсылают за ответом к другому примечанию**
>
> Если читателя приходится отсылать за пояснением от данного примечания
>   к другому, то перекрестная ссылка должна адресовать читателя к тому
>   примечанию, которое содержит ответ, а не к промежуточному, в свою
>   очередь переадресовывающему к примечанию с ответом; заставлять
>   читателя тратить время на такие лишние перелистывания страниц
>   недопустимо.

**[источник](http://www.az-print.com/index.shtml?FAQ&HelpBook/h027)**

Comment: Спасибо за подробное пояснение. Но здесь конкретно по вопросу одно: авторские сноски находятся под строками, издательские — за текстом. Я бы хотел более развернутого ответа именно о примерах реализации сносок в сносках. Быть может,  известны другие способы оформления этого случая.

Comment: Если я, полиграфист, не нашла, то и никто не найдёт. Главный принцип тут - смотрибельность, то есть эстетическая сторона. Я бы смело нарисовала к существующей сноске, в скобках: "*Примечание к примечанию*. <Текст>. - **Авт./Ред.**"