# Ссылка на сноску

Tags: другое

Возможна ли ссылка на сноску в таком виде:
Текст* (см. также**), где * и ** - надстрочные номера сносок, т.е. нужно дать ссылку на два разных источника (второй дополнительный, поэтому в скобках).
Сложность в объяснении из-за того, что не могу набрать здесь надстрочные знаки.
Вот конкретное предложение.
Даже обыкновенные люди, не имеющие отношения к оккультным практикам, регулярно в той или иной степени прибегают к бытовой магии (охранительной, лечебной, хозяйственной, погодной, любовной и даже вредоносной)* (см. также**).

Comment: Возможно, Вы имели в виду оформление сносок в сносках? Эту информацию можно посмотреть здесь: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/436842/Как-оформляют-сноски-в-сносках

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Возможна ли ссылка на сноску в таком виде:
>
> Текст* (см. также**)

В таком виде ссылку на сноску дать нельзя. Ссылка не может относиться к слову "также". Чтобы дать более точный ответ на Ваш вопрос, хотелось бы видеть более подробный контекст.

Один из возможных вариантов:

*В работе Иванова* (см. также работу Петрова**)*

Comment: Текст выглядит так:"Цитата"* (см. также**). Автор ставит ссылки к цитатам без указания их автора (эта инфа даётся в сноске). Поэтому, если указать фамилию другого автора, то нарушится единообразие. А нельзя дать подряд два номера ссылки (они цифровые) через зпт?

Comment: Зря Вы не привели реальный пример. Можете отредактировать вопрос. Здесь важно, чтобы предложение было самодостаточным. Сравните следующие варианты: (а) это изучалось в работах [1], [2] (см. также [3]); (б) это изучалось в работах* (см. также**). Пункт (а) ссылается на список литературы и так можно сказать, а вот п.(б) ссылается на сноски и так нельзя писать, потому что предложение само по себе теряет структуру. Проблема здесь не в фамилиях. (Сноска не может служить в предложении обстоятельством или определением.)

Comment: Уточнил вопрос.

Comment: @Рад Так нельзя. Конечно можно дать все ссылки через запятые. Это правильное решение.

Comment: Тогда потеряется смысл дополнительности второго источника, ведь первая ссылка даётся на конкретные слова (смысл).

Comment: Тогда разверните эту "дополнительность" отдельным самодостаточным предложением. В данном случае я затрудняюсь предложить Вам другие варианты (хотя это не означает, что их нет :)

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, будем думать.